# @Resource injection not happening in JAX-RS

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jax-rs, cdi

When `@ApplicationScoped` is not specified on a JAX-RS resource, line below,
@Resource injection for `ManagedExecutorService` does not happen and I have encountered `NullPointerException`.

But when I add `@ApplicationScoped` along with `@Path`, I can see that `ManagedExecutorService` resource injection has happened properly.

Please help to figure out the difference between JAX-RS resource when 
only `@Path("/uri")` is used and when `@Path("/uri")` is used along with along with `@ApplicationScoped`/`@RequestScoped`.

IDE and server used are Netbeans and Glassfish 5 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The lifecycle of the resource class instance is either managed by CDI or JAX-RS. Once you add the `@ApplicationScoped` on the resource class, it becomes managed by CDI. Thats the difference. If it's not CDI managed, you can't inject a CDI `@Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

Resource can be only injected for container managed class.

Comment: Instance for the below class is automartically created by container when request 
comes to the uri .../mes. Is it not conatiner managed class by default?

@Path("/mes")    
public class RestResource    
{              
       @Resource    
       ManagedExecutorService mes;